# Using moment.js to convert a javascript date received from C# View model

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller, momentjs

Title says it all.  I've been fighting this for awhile now. 
I receive a csharp date and its in this format:

```
/Date(1483423200000)/
```

Heres the code:

```
<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o pull-right" aria-hidden="true" onclick="editNote('@note.Id')"></i>

function editNote(noteId) {
        var notes = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

        for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
            var tempNote = notes[i];

            if (tempNote.Id == noteId) {
                console.log(new Date(tempNote.Date));
                var calDateToString = moment(JSON.stringify(tempNote.Date), "dddd, MMMM, D, yyyy");
                console.log(calDateToString);
                var note = JSON.stringify({
                    Id: tempNote.Id,
                    Date: ToJavaScriptDate(tempNote.Date),
                    Title: tempNote.Title,
                    Comments: tempNote.Comments
                });
            }
        }

        var url = '/Calendar/DisplayEditNote';
        EditModalInfo(url, note);
    }

    function EditModalInfo(url, note) {
        //close displaymodal
        $("#calendarModal").modal('hide');
        $('.modal-backdrop').remove();

        //format date Tuesday, January 3, 2017
        var calDateToString = moment(note.Date, "dddd, MMMM, D, yyyy");

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: note,
            success: function (result) {
                $("#modalBodyContainer").html(result);
                $("#modal-date").text(calDateToString);
                $("#calendarModal").modal('show');
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                console.log(request.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

When I do a console.log({ JSON.stringify(note)) this is the output:

```
"{\"Id\":5,\"Date\":\"1/3/2017\",\"Title\":\"one\",\"Comments\":\"moretime\"}"
```

I have been banging my head trying to do this manually and now i've installed the moment.js library to fix it and still having no luck... how do i convert it to look like this:

```
Tuesday, January 3, 2017
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `moment.format()` to produce the output you're looking for. See this plnkr.

http://plnkr.co/edit/KFgmXqz01GmqY7y20seG?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing parsing the date with formatting it.

`moment(note.Date, "dddd, MMMM, D, yyyy")` *parses* `note.Date` assuming it is in the specified format. If `note.Date` is `1483423200000`, you can instantiate a moment object from it by just:

```
var yourDate = moment(note.Date);
```

Once you have the moment, you can display it in any format you like by using its `format` function, here's an example using the format you're looking for:

```
var calDateToString = yourDate.format('dddd, MMMM, D, YYYY'); // "Tuesday, January, 3, 2017"
```